Energy as mean of absolutes of data samples
Normally, we find the energy of a given signal as $\sum{{x_n}^2}$. But, what if I compute, energy as $\sum{|x_n|}$. In the latter case, if I want energy in dB, which formula should I use - $10\log_{10}(\text{Energy})$ or $20\log_{10}(\text{Energy})$??

In signal processing, energy is defined as $\sum x_n^2$.  In math, unless your signal is a constant, you cannot find correction constants such that $\sum x_n^2 = b + m \left(\sum |x_n|\right)^2$.  What you are trying to do is tantamount to setting $b = 0$ and implicitly squaring the sum of the absolute values in the scale of the log "power" function.  So -- you can't get there from here.  You cannot, in general, calculate power from a sum of absolute values.

If you have some specific use case for which you think a very coarse approximation of power is useful, then you should edit your question to spell out the details for us, and ask for help in getting a good-enough approximation within the constraints you're putting on your math.  You'll need to tell us the properties of the signal that may make the math work (or the application in which you're seeing this done), and the degree to which inaccuracies are acceptable.

Power and Energy estimation can and is done using mean of absolute values, or alternatively the mean of the magnitudes, due to the simplification it provides over "True-RMS" measurements based on the square root of the mean of the squares.
Consider computing the root-mean-square for a signal $x[n]$, which I refer to as "True-RMS":
$$x_{rms} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_0^{N-1}x^2[n]}$$
The alternative Absolute Magnitude estimator is given as:
$$\hat{x}_{abs}  = \frac{1}{N}\sum_0^{N-1}|x[n]|$$
The result in dB for both cases is 20 Log as both are magnitude quantities (and if squared would be power quantities where 10 Log would be used).
This approach results in an error that is dependent on the distribution of the waveform since the "mean of the squares" is not the same as the "square of the mean", but is practical due to its simplicity when we only need a result proportional to power for a given waveform.
The Absolute Magnitude estimator is identical to the "Mean Absolute Deviation" for real zero-mean signals. From this link we see that the ratio of the mean absolute deviation to the standard deviation (which would be the "true-rms" for zero-mean signals) for a Gaussian distribution is $\sqrt{2/\pi}$ or $20\log_{10}(\sqrt{2/\pi}) = -1.96$ dB.
The Absolute Magnitude estimator for complex zero-mean Gaussian signals in comparison has a Rayleigh distribution, and as explained nicely in HP App-Note 1303, has a ratio of the mean of the absolute magnitudes to the standard deviation to be $\sqrt{\pi/4}$ or $20\log_{10}(\sqrt{\pi/4}) = -1.05$ dB.
Those are the errors for waveforms consistent with a normal (Gaussian) distribution, resulting in an under-estimate of -1.96 dB or -1.05 dB for the case or real or complex waveforms. The error will be different for other distributions. This is similar to the considerations given for using analog power detectors where we can estimate power by averaging the output of a diode detector or use a true-rms power detector.
(Observe in the error results above we could more directly compute each using $10\log_{10}(2/\pi)$ and $10\log_{10}(\pi/4)$ but I wanted to continue to use 20 Log as further demonstration of using that for magnitude quantities).

and it's worth noting that the ratios of central and non-central moments of different orders (such as of the first and second order here) are classical tools of SNR estimation and modulation recognition – exactly because Gaussian noise contributes differently to different orders. So, if you don't know the kind of signal and the amount of noise to expect, you can't infer as much about the power from knowing the average magnitudes. Nice aspect to bring in the diode detector!

Noted! thank you Marcus

Absolutely -- you can estimate it.  But you can't get an exact measurement.  In the case of the OP's original question, if you're going to use sum-of-squares then you have an energy estimate and in dB you'd take 10 log (energy) -- without having to take the square root.  If you're going to use sum-of-absolute then you'd have an amplitude estimate and for the amplitude in dB you'd take 20 log (amplitude) -- but you wouldn't necessarily have a measurement of energy, just a possibly-useful measurement of amplitude (ish).

@TimWescott no disagreement with that. I think (or hope) I was getting to the root of the OP's question with 10 or 20 log and (hopefully) detailed the limitations. I think we can bottom line the answer as: if you want an estimate using sum of absolute you would do 20 Log.
